# Execute commands on a remote servers by 2 scripts

Tags: bash, scripts, ssh

Currently I am using `SSHPass` in a script to connect to a remote server:

```
sshpass -p PASSWORD ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no USERNAME@1.1.1.1
```

and to execute any command remotely, I use:

```
sshpass -p PASSWORD ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no USERNAME@1.1.1.1 "COMMAND"
```

I am planning to separate the connection step in one script (`conn.sh`) and the commands in another (`cmd.sh`).

I tried this way:

cmd.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
ls -ltr
```

conn.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash    
sshpass -p PASSWORD ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no USERNAME@1.1.1.1 "$1"
```

And execution after giving both scripts "chmod a+x":

```
./conn.sh cmd.sh
```

But it gave me error:

```
cmd.sh: command not found
```

I even tried to replace `$1` with the path to `cmd.sh`, but it gave me this error:

```
sh: /home/myhome/cmd.sh: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Did you create `cmd.sh` on the remote machine, or on the local machine?

Comment: local, beside the "conn.sh"

Comment: As i want to execute commands in my local "cmd.sh" on that remote machine, and can also apply it for any other remote machine.

Comment: Do not use passwords. Set up `ssh_config` and ssh-keys and you don't need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Even if i used the keys instead of the password, how can i execute the script "cmd.sh" which should have multiple commands from inside "conn.sh"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it fails is that when you run something like

```
ssh user@remote command
```

The `command` is not only run on the remote machine, it is also searched for on the remote machine. Therefore, when you run `./conn.sh cmd.sh`, you are connecting to the remote and then you are trying to run a script called `cmd.sh` *on the remote*. Since there is no such script (it's stored on your local machine), the execution fails and you see that error.

You can do what you describe by changing your `conn.sh` to:

```
#!/bin/bash
sshpass -p PASSWORD ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no USERNAME@1.1.1.1 \
 bash -s < "$1"
```

And then run

```
./conn.sh /local/path/to/cmd.sh
```

That will open a bash shell on the remote machine. The `-s` tells bash to read commands from standard input and the `< "$1"` provides the 1st argument given to `conn.sh` as the input to that bash shell.

Are you sure you need to do this though? What you describe is almost certainly an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/203101). The simple solution is to create the `cmd.sh` on the remote server. Then you can do

```
./conn.sh /remote/path/to/cmd.sh
```

Comment: It make full sense to me now, Worked like a charm!, thanks alot, yes i guess i fall into the XY trap :(, i avoided creating the cmd.sh on the server, as i will need it for all my servers i have, so as not to create or copy it to all of them,

Comment: @user225844 You're welcome. I suggest you post a separate question explaining what your final objective is. If you do, leave me a comment here and I'll try to answer. You might be looking for [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/), for example.